# Using StreamSocket to receive data correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, windows-phone-8.1, supersocket.net

I've been developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app that sends and receives data using a `StreamSocket`. I was having issues with the receiving of large data on the phone. I've written some code that I think deals with this however I'm not sure if it's sufficient enough or if I've thought of everything:

```
Public Async Function ReceiveResponse() As Task(Of XDocument)

    Dim xResponse As New XDocument
    Dim response As String = String.Empty
    Dim byteCount As UInteger = 1024

    Dim dataReader As New DataReader(_streamSocket.InputStream)

    Try
        With dataReader
            .InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial

            Await .LoadAsync(byteCount)

            Do Until response.EndsWith(vbCrLf)
                response += .ReadString(.UnconsumedBufferLength)
                If Not response.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
                    Await .LoadAsync(byteCount)
                End If
            Loop

            xResponse = XDocument.Parse(response.Replace(vbCrLf, ""))
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        xResponse = XDocument.Parse("<Response><Error>" & ex.Message & "</Error></Response>")
    Finally
        With dataReader
            .DetachStream()
            .Dispose()
        End With
    End Try

    Return xResponse

End Function
```

> Note that I use something called [SuperSocket](http://www.supersocket.net/) on the communication server which handles the message and sends the response. To send from or receive to the communication server I have to append `vbCrLf` to the end of the message. If I don't do this the message is not sent or received.

With this in mind you can see from the code that I check for `vbCrLf` when receiving the stream on the phone:

```
Await .LoadAsync(byteCount)

Do Until response.EndsWith(vbCrLf)
    response += .ReadString(.UnconsumedBufferLength)
    If Not response.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
        Await .LoadAsync(byteCount)
    End If
Loop
```

At the office this works however we have no interference with our Wi-Fi. When we setup for shows in venues where there could be 100s of other companies each with their own systems that use Wi-Fi we obviously notice large interference and this creates the appearance of slow Wi-Fi.

To provide context, this was my original code which I had issues with:

```
Public Async Function ReceiveResponse() As Task(Of XDocument)

    Dim xResponse As New XDocument

    Dim dataReader As New DataReader(_streamSocket.InputStream)

    Try
        With dataReader
            .InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial

            Dim actualStringLength As UInt32 = Await .LoadAsync(9999999)

            If actualStringLength > 0 Then
                xResponse = XDocument.Parse(.ReadString(actualStringLength))
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        xResponse = XDocument.Parse("<Response><Error>" & ex.Message & "</Error></Response>")
    Finally
        With dataReader
            .DetachStream()
            .Dispose()
        End With
    End Try

    Return xResponse

End Function
```

> Note the difference here. I tried to load up the entire stream with `.LoadAsync(9999999)` thinking that by increasing to *9999999* that would return everything. Obviously this is not the case. I didn't do any checking for the response being finished.

My question is, can anybody see an issue with the code and the checking of `vbCrLf` to ensure I've received all the message? Has anybody a better way of handling this?

Comment: Looks like you're missing [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, thanks for the reply. I've had a read and I think I'm doing that using the delimiter vbcrlf although maybe not in the most efficient way. I check for the vbcrlf which all the messages sent end with. If I don't find it at the end of the received message I go off and call .LoadAsync(byteCount) again to get the next lot.

Comment: `If I don't find it at the end of the received message` - this is the problem. You don't receive messages - just bytes in a stream. To properly delimit on CRLF, you'll need search within your already-received bytes to find it.

Comment: I thought by appending `.ReadString(.UnconsumedBufferLength)` to the variable `response` and then checking this variable for ending in CRLF that I was doing that? Appending: `response += .ReadString(.UnconsumedBufferLength)`. Checking: `If Not response.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then`. Or am I completely missing the point here? The server side is using **SuperSocket** which ends all messages with CRLF.

Comment: No. The socket abstraction is a stream, not messages.